# Return a new string containing all characters of original string with underscores between each character

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, charat

I'm trying to create a method where the currentString is returned with underscores in the middle of each character. For example, if the current string is: "hi there" the output string would be `h_i__t_h_e_r_e` with no underscore at the beginning or end. I'm aware this can be done with regex and replaceAll, but I'm trying to accomplish this with a for loop instead

My current code looks like this:

```
 public String spacedWord()
    {
            String spacedString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i<currentString.length(); i++)
            {
                spacedString = spacedString+currentString.charAt(i)+"_";
            
            }
            return spacedString;
            
    }
```

If the current string is "hey there" my code returns `h_e_y_ _t_h_e_r_e_` with an underscore at the end.

The code returns properly with underscores in between each character, but I'm not sure how make sure an underscore doesn't appear at the end of the string.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For some reason it won't let me type the underscore but for clarity my code outputs a underscore after the e in "hey there"

Comment: hint: try using [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)), in combination with [length](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()) to return `spaceString` with one less character.

Comment: The two examples are inconsistent. In the first, the blank is removed, but in the second it remains.  What is the actual requirement?

Comment: It appears in your example, in addition to the unwanted `_` at the end, the blank space is to be removed, but is present in your example of actual output. Is the blank space, in fact to be removed?  Edit hint: It will help to put example input, expected output, and actual output between backtick (`) characters, as might be done with a short piece of code.

Comment: The blank is to remain, my fault

Comment: Java 8 Streams solution: `Pattern.compile("").splitAsStream("hey there").collect(joining("_"))` (smiley not intended) (Warning will not work for all Unicode Characters)

Answer (score 0):

The "-1" trick.

```
String spacedString = "";
String currentString= "Hello Peaple";
for (int i = 0; i<currentString.length()-1; i++)
{
    spacedString = spacedString+currentString.charAt(i)+"_";
}
spacedString = spacedString+currentString.charAt(currentString.length()-1);
return spacedString;
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm not sure how make sure an underscore doesn't appear at the end of the string. ..."*

Skip the first index, and prepend the underscore.

```java
String spacedString = "";
for (int i = 0; i<currentString.length(); i++)
{
    if (i != 0) spacedString += "_";
    spacedString += currentString.charAt(i);

}
return spacedString;
```

Alternately, use a *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* to insert the *char*.  Iterate backwards, to avoid the increasing length.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(currentString);
for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) s.insert(i, '_');
```

Or, utilize a *for-loop* and the *[String#toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())* method.

```java
String spacedString = "";
int i = 0;
for (char c : currentString.toCharArray())
{
    if (i++ != 0) spacedString += '_';
    spacedString += c;

}
return spacedString;
```

Or, use a *stream*, and the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))* method.

```java
String spacedString
    = String.join("_", currentString.chars()
                                    .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf((char) x))
                                    .toList());
```

Output

```
h_i_ _t_h_e_r_e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for a one-liner:

```
public static String spacedWord() {
    return currentString.replaceAll("(?<=\\S) *(?=\\S)", "_");
}
```

This works by replacing all places in the string that are *between* non-space characters =, optionally including any spaces, with an underscore.

This expression `(?<=\\S)` is a lookbehind (an assertion) for any non-space character while this expression `(?=\\S)` is a lookahead (an assertion) for any non-space character.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use string additions within loops; it pollutes the heap. Instead use a `StringBuilder`:

```
public String spacedWord()
{
  StringBuilder spacedString = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0, l = currentString.length(); i < l; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
      spacedString.append('_');
    spacedString.append(currentString.charAt(i));      
  }

  return spacedString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this code piece as well. The concept here is to delay the appending of underscore until a non-space character is encountered.

```
public static String spacedWord(String currentString) {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(currentString.length());
    int underscoreLength = 0;
    boolean hasFirstNonspaceChar = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < currentString.length(); i++) {

        char c = currentString.charAt(i);
        // ignore leading space
        if (c == ' ' && !hasFirstNonspaceChar) {
            underscoreLength = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if ( c == ' ') {
            // delay the appending of underscore with a counter
            underscoreLength++;
        } else {
            if (!hasFirstNonspaceChar) {
                hasFirstNonspaceChar = true;
            } else {
                // increment the count of underscore needs to be prepended before next character
                underscoreLength++;
            }
            prependUnderscore(sb, underscoreLength);
            underscoreLength = 0; // reset the counter
            sb.append(c);
        }

    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void prependUnderscore(StringBuilder sb, int length) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        sb.append('_');
    }
}
```

Test:

public static void main(String[] args) {
String input;

```
    SpaceWord sw = new SpaceWord();

    input = "hi there";
    System.out.println(sw.spacedWord(input));

    input = " hi there";
    System.out.println(sw.spacedWord(input));

    input = "  hi there";
    System.out.println(sw.spacedWord(input));

    input = "hi there ";
    System.out.println(sw.spacedWord(input));

    input = "hi there  ";
    System.out.println(sw.spacedWord(input));
}
```

Output:

```
h_i__t_h_e_r_e
h_i__t_h_e_r_e
h_i__t_h_e_r_e
h_i__t_h_e_r_e
h_i__t_h_e_r_e
```